# Using an API to display a HTML table that has images and title of a movie

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on an assignment to create a online movie shopping cart. It is a very basic assignment but I am stuck on one thing. I need to create an HTML table after receiving a search result from the user. The user will be searching for a movie by a keyword and I have to pull up every movie that has that keyword in it.

Could anyone give me tips on how to go about making this table work properly? I am lost on how to even begin to get it to display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['displayName'];
?>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:confirmLogout()">(Logout)</a>
<html id= "movie-color">
    <head>
        <title> Search </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/site.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h2 id="movie-title"> myMovies Xpress! </h2>
            <br>
        </div>
        <?php
        if (empty($_POST["keyword"])){
            $searchErr = "Movie Name Is Required";
        }else{
            $keyword = ($_POST["keyword"]);
        }
        if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {
            $results = file_get_contents('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[7491f5e4]&s=' . urlencode([keyword]) . '&type=movie&r=json');
            $array = json_decode($results, true)["Search"];
        }
        ?>
        <?php if (count($array) > 0): ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <form action="search.php" method="post">
            <label> Search: </label>
            <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" value=""<?php echo $keyword;?>/>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $searchErr;?></span>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="Search" value="Login">Search</button>
        </form>
            <button type="button" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code. then your input tag isn't correct.

Comment: one more thing is don't put your validation form on the top.. instead put it    in search.php

Comment: @basaya How would I use a loop to create the different rows? Also will do, but just curious is there a reason for that or is it just to make it make more sense to someone who is looking at it?

Answer (score 1):

ok. here is my tips for you. To display the data to table tag you must do this correctly and neatly..

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
            <label> Search: </label>
            <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword;?>"/> // your keyword variable must be inside in the value attribute
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $searchErr;?></span>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Login">Search /> // if you are using button tag, type, name, value attributes are not necessary. 
        </form>
            <button type="button" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
```

to display the data.

```
 <table> 
     <?php
        foreach ($data as $key) { //$data is the return data from database
        # code...
      ?>
          <tr>
               <td> <?php echo $key->column_name?> </td> //if your data is JSON  $key['column_name']
         </tr>
      <?php
          }
       ?>
     </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I didn't even realize the keyword wasn't in the value attribute. This really helped a lot.

Comment: no problem. hope this will help you to analyze the code.